# Call a function without knowing it's name

Tags: php

I want to create a function in PHP and to call it without knowing the function's name.

Is this possible?

Example:

```
<?php

     $functionName = "someName";
     $this->$functionName();
     function someName(){
         echo("Print Message");
     }
?>
```

Comment: `without knowing the function's name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

```
$functionName = "someName";
call_user_func($functionName); //calls `someName()`
```

Can be used like the following where the output is the printed message "Hello, World!":

```
function someName($val){
    return $val;
}

$functionName = "someName";
echo call_user_func($functionName, "Hello, World!");
```

http://ideone.com/Kw5jp

**Note:** If you're using newer versions of PHP, you can also use callables as @J.Bruni pointed out:

```
$functionName = "someName";
$functionName(); //also calls `someName()`
```

Comment: I tried both options and both works, was really helpful, thanks

Comment: use the outlined checkmark next to the post in order to select an answer

Comment: "callables" is not something new. They are available for a long time. `is_callable` function is available since PHP 4.0.6. The fact is that the new "callables" documentation page is terribly worst than it was before... I just had this unpleasant surprise after pasting the link in my answer... the page I wanted to link does not exist anymore!

Comment: The only thing that is new is that you can use the "callable" word as type hint: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is simple:

```
$functionName();
```

Yet, you have several other options, allowing more complex stuff. Please check:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

A collection of examples:

```
function test() { echo 'hello 1'; }
class Something { function test() { echo 'hello 2'; } }
class Other { static function test() { echo 'hello 3'; } }

$functionName = 'test';
$object = new Something();
$className = 'Other';

// three ways to call function "test", showing how to pass parameters
$functionName($param1, $param2);
call_user_func($functionName, $param1, $param2);
call_user_func_array($functionName, array($param1, $param2));

// two ways to call "Something::test"
$object->$functionName();
call_user_func(array($object, $functionName));

// a way to call "Other::test"
call_user_func(array($className, $functionName));
```

Important: you need to declare the function **before** calling it. (In your question, you are declaring the function **after** trying to call it. This doesn't work.)

To avoid errors, you can use the function [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) to verify if a function/method is callable before actually calling it.

Comment: This is the best way imo. There is no reason to use `call_user_func` for cases like this, although you should check the function's existence with `function_exists`.

Comment: Yes, sure. You certainly don't **need** `call_user_func` for what is being asked. It can be useful in several scenarios, but of course you can call a function using a string variable without using it.

Comment: I tried both options and both works, yours and @Nile, was really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

call_user_func() solves your problems!

```
$function = 'myOwnFunction';
call_user_func( $functionname );
```

and to avoid fatal errors, you

```
function_exists($function);
```

with it!

Comment: there is no difference between @nile and your answer

Comment: only difference is between me and nile, he seems to be faster to type than me ^^